# How can I save and export the settings letting apps be attached to workspaces?

Tags: macos

In macOS, it is easy to assign an app to a workspace so that every time the app is launched it is automatically opening in the designated workspace.

Where is that information stored so that I could make it part of my config files that I install on any macOS that I use (instead of having to manually reassign apps each time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In macOS, it is easy to assign an app to a workspace so that every time the app is launched it is automatically opening in the designated workspace.
>
> Where is that information stored

That information is stored in:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist
```

Under the `app-bindings` *key*.

In **Terminal** you can use:

```
defaults read com.apple.spaces.plist app-bindings
```

To see what *application* are bound to a particular **Desktop/Space**.

As an example, here is a snippet from the *command* above:

```
 % defaults read com.apple.spaces.plist app-bindings
{
    "org.videolan.vlc" = "F124EFFD-7A6E-4B41-851E-2DD708E826E8";
}
%
```

Where `F124EFFD-7A6E-4B41-851E-2DD708E826E8` is the **UUID** of my second **Desktop/Space** and this Information is elsewhere in the **.plist** *file*.

---

> so that I could make it part of my config files that I install on any macOS that I use (instead of having to manually reassign apps each time)?

The **UUID** of a **Desktop/Space** is going to be unique from one **Mac** to another, so while one can get the information from the **com.apple.spaces.plist** *file*, nonetheless, one would have to write a *script* that with get the **UUID** of each **Desktop/Space** on that different **Mac** and apply it to the *application's* **Bundle ID** in the  `app-bindings` *key*.

You will also have issues with how to get the updated information on the different **Mac** to take effect, but lets say that's outside the scope of the question asked.

---

**Notes:**

**.plist** *files* are **XML Property Lists**, however, some are in *binary* format.

You can use the `plutil` *command* to convert a copy of the target *file* to **ASCII XML**.

See the *manual pages* for both `plutil` and `defaults`.

You can read the *manual page* for *`command`* in **Terminal** by typing *`man command`*, then press **enter**, or **for easier reading**, just type *`command`* and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

There is also `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` that can work with **.plist** *files*.

Comment: My `com.apple.spaces.plist` file is not really human readable, what is the format?

Comment: @Damien L, RE: "My com.apple.spaces.plist file is not really human readable, what is the format? " --  They are **XML Property Lists**, however, some are in _binary_ format.

Comment: I am used to the XML Property Lists, I didn't know some could be in binary format. Why are some of them in binary?

Comment: @Damien L, RE: "Why are some of them in binary?" --  You would have to ask **Apple** why. You can use the `plutil` _command_ to convert a copy of the target _file_ to **ASCII  XML**.  See the _manual pages_ for both `plutil` and `defaults`.